# how can store a Json in redis with hashmap( HSET )

Tags: node.js, redis, hashmap

i have a question about HSET in redis. As far as i know, redis is a key-value database. that means every thing store as a key-value and we don't have table for example.
i wanted to save something in redis so i decided to use Hashmap . since the HMSET is deprecated and we should use HSET instead, how should I store many attribute as a value and a id as a key in hset? 
you know i want to save some thing like this:

```
await redis.hset(`origin-${originId}`, 'title',title)
```

but if i have many fields to save i should write this line for each field?? for example :

```
await redis.hset(`origin-${originId}`, 'title',title)
await redis.hset(`origin-${originId}`, 'status',status)
...
```

as in HSET we should define 3 parameter i write this code. Isn't there a better solution?

Comment: Did you check redisjson.io?

Comment: @GuyKorland no, how should i use this in my example?

Comment: have u gone through [this](https://medium.com/@stockholmux/store-javascript-objects-in-redis-with-node-js-the-right-way-1e2e89dbbf64) ?

Comment: @Praga_t this is for old version that support hmset. but my issue is with hset in version 5 of redis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure out that my problem was with my redis client. my redise version is 5 but my redis client doesn't support new features in Redis 5.
so i use **ioredis**  and this redis client support hmset now. also there is a fix for that issue but wasn't released yet see [enter link description here](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/pull/1012)

Answer (score 7):

you can do this

```sh
hset key field1 value1 field2 value2 ...
```

It's documented here

https://redis.io/commands/hmset and https://redis.io/commands/hset

but `hmset` is deprecated and you should use `hset` now because it supports the same args as `hmset`

in node.js, if you already have the key / value in an object, you can do this

```js
await redis.hset('myhashset', { field1: value1, field2: value2 })
```

Comment: i do this and get this error: ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command

Comment: ah chance are you are using an old version of redis. this is supported since redis 4 and current version is 5. can you check your redis version? in case it's not support, you can just use `hmset`

Comment: my Redis server version is 4.0.9 and ioredis client is 4.14.1

Comment: ioredis -> use `hmset`, there is a fix for that but wasn't released yet see (https://github.com/luin/ioredis/pull/1012)