# ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command in redis when add a json

Tags: node.js, redis, hashmap

i asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59352905/how-can-store-a-json-in-redis-with-hashmap-hset?noredirect=1#comment104905151_59352905) and based on answers i rewrite my code simliar to this :

```
await redis.hset(`origin-${originId}`, { title, status, location })
```

but now i get an error that say: 
**{ ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command**

i was upgrade my redis-server to vesion 5.0.7. how should i resolve this issue ? please help me.

Comment: Just use `hmset` for now. There is a fix for that but wasn't released yet see (https://github.com/luin/ioredis/pull/1012).

Comment: @ItamarHaber 
in use of hmset, i get this error again : { ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hset` command requires at least 3 arguments: hashname, key, value.

See [the Redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/hset). You are not able to store a JavaScript object as a redis hash. Instead, you will need to spread your object out and use the `hmset` command. Something like this will work.

```
await redis.hset(`origin-${originId}`, 'title', title, 'status', status, 'location', location);
```

If you have a large object with many keys you want to set at once, you will need to spread it out first. Something like this will work:

```
await redis.hset(`origin-${originId}`,  Object.entries(largeObject).flat());
```

---

**EDIT**

Looks like you can now [use the `hmset` command](http://redis.js.org/#api-friendlier-hash-commands-clienthmsethash-obj-callback) in node-redis without having to spread the parameters out. So simply doing this should be enough:

```
await redis.hmset(`origin-${originId}`,  largeObject);
```

This format will only work for the `hmset` command, not the `hset` command.

Comment: @AaronStainback can you please post what the correct answer is?

Comment: ["As per Redis 4.0.0, HMSET is considered deprecated. Please use HSET in new code."](https://redis.io/commands/hmset)