# ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redis, node-redis

I using typescript in new project and I have an error using redis hset command. I use:

```
await this.client.HSET(`users:${key}`, dataToSave);
```

I have read that hset apply **3 arguments**. When I add third one

```
await this.client.HSET(`users:${key}`, dataToSave, dataToSave)
```

I have error:

*Argument of type '[string, string[], string[]]' is not
assignable to parameter of type '[key: RedisCommandArgument, field: Types, value: Types] | [key: RedisCommandArgument, value: HSETObject | HSETMap | HSETTuples] | [options: ...] | [options: ...]'*.

I am new to typscript. Please help. What should the third argument look like?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is likely caused by the fact that you're passing an array as the second argument (dataToSave), but the second argument should be a string representing the field name.

Alternatively, you can pass an object as the second argument to specify multiple field/value pairs at once:

```
await this.client.HSET(`users:${key}`, {
  field1: 'value1',
  field2: 'value2',
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work ;/

Comment: you have the some error ?

Comment: [ErrorReply: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command]
{"name":"server","hostname":"Komputronik","pid":13696,"level":50,"msg":"Error: \u001b[41mServer error. Try again.\u001b[49m","time":"2022-12-27T10:04:58.202Z","v":0}

Comment: I recommend double-checking that you are providing the correct number of arguments to the HSET command and that the arguments are of the correct type.

Comment: i found this it may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/59373481/12885839

Comment: The message "ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command" is generated by Redis. This means that Node Redis is sending commands to Redis that it doesn't understand. This is most likely because you are using an old version of Redis. The variadic version of HSET that Node Redis uses was added in Redis 4.0.